# Spring Tool Suite 4.7.1 editor bugs after update

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I recently updated to version 4.7.1 of Spring Tool Suite on my Ubuntu 16 and since then two strange bugs have appeared in my editor. I wonder if it is STS/Eclipse bugs or if my cat has changed some setting to cause this (yes, she likes lying on the warm laptop keyboard, logging in as admin, opening stuff and changing settings. Don't ask me how...)

1. When placing marker anywhere and then click-dragging anywhere (to mark a word or a few lines) the entire visible page get's marked from the top to where I had marked.

[image]

2. I can no longer ctrl+click a Java class to go into it's class file as I used to. I also can no longer hover a marked error to get suggestions for solutions like I used to. No hover at all is present.

- I have tried searching the editor settings and resetting to default.
- I have tried uninstalling STS and installing again, and SAME issues!
- I have tried multiple online keyboard checkers and they don't mark
  any keys as being "held down constantly" or stuck.
- I tried installing Eclipse (not STS) and the **same issue appears
  there.**
- No issues in  Gedit or Visual Code.
- I tried connecting external mouse and keyboard, same problem as using native laptop mousepad or keyboard.

Is anyone else having this problems with Eclipse or STS?

Comment: That sounds as if your cat enabled Caps Lock or that the shift key is permanently pressed. If you on Windows 10, run the built-in _On-Screen Keyboard_ to see if any keys are pressed or some locks are enabled. You might also check if you see similar behavior in applications other than Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger I'm on Ubuntu 16 and no keys are pressed as you suggest, all other application works fine.

Comment: Which Eclipse version? If it's the current version [make sure you have GTK 3.20 or higher](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version).

Comment: @howlger That seems to have solved the "mark all" bug, thanks! Add as answer and I'll mark as correct. The other "hover" issue was caused by "tools.jar" not being available in my JDK, so I added this to my SpringToolSuite4.ini file to solve it:
-vm
/path/to/my/java/bin/java

As described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Selection issue: **On Linux** make sure to use the **right GTK version**, which is for the current **[Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) GTK 3.20 or higher](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version)**
2. Hover issue: [As you have found out yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669203/spring-tool-suite-4-7-1-editor-bugs-after-update?noredirect=1#comment112592936_63669203), make sure to **run Eclipse with the right Java VM** ([which can be specified in the `eclipse.ini` file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM))